# What is "Network Infrastructure" feature in Windows Exploer?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-explorer

On a Windows 7 machine in Windows Explorer under Network subtree I can also see node called "Network Infrastructure" and my wireless modem is listed here? Could someone please point me to documentation on this feature and maybe explain in brief what is it about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router likely suuports [Universal Plug-n-Play Internet Gateway Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#NAT_traversal) profile.  This allows applications to configure ports that are forwarded from the internet to other devices on your network.